# Teaching of smuh?

Tags: meaning, dictionaries

I was helping my child with her homework and noticed that she has to learn words starting with with sm..., st....

I found word "smuh" which i had never seen before as English is not my native language & looked into my English dictionary on my phone and could not find it & while searching for it on internet i found

example
http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=smuh

*shake my unicorn head.
same meaning as "smh" but the added word "unicorn" puts the speaker higher above the other. Therefore, making themselves more dominant. Basically a classy way to judge someone using an abbreviation that they won't understand.
Dumb friend: "I just bought Justin Bieber's new cd!"
Cooler 'unicorn' friend: "... smuh."*

I am bit lost with it. Is it a slang kind of words should it be taught to children at such an early age?

My basic question is do teachers actually teach children such words in "grade 1"? Or do children learn them from "random" places such as the Internet? Or even "mislearn" them when the teacher is teaching another word, such as "smush?"

`UPDATE`:

Smug was also listed in the list, I am not ruling it out as a mistake on child part as she copied it from white board. But on the other side teacher had marker it as correct (✓). so i also doubt my child had made a mistake unless teacher was not absent minded.

Comment: No word I've ever heard.  I suspect it was a typo.

Comment: It's an acronym I've never seen. But I don't know any Beliebers.

Comment: Spelling mistakes in the spelling lists given to schoolchildren are worryingly commonplace.

Comment: I made the question more objective by asking if teachers DO teach children such words, rather than "should" they, and wonder if it can be re-opened in its current form.

Comment: It was a typo, (nowadays teachers write everything up on their computers) note that the key -g on the keyboard is right beside the letter -h key *smuh* --> *smug*, or double typo: *snug*. I'd hazard a guess that 97.5% of the English speaking population is unaware of smuh's existence.

Comment: Outside of interjections, English words don’t normally end with *-uh*, so this doesn’t look Englishy.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, Smug was also listed in the list, I am not ruling it out as a mistake on child part as she copied it from white board. But on the other side teacher had marker it as correct (✓). so i also doubt my child has made a mistake

Comment: Bingo! Your child read the letter -h as -n As I used to teach English to small children, this is a common transcription error. Um... "smun". Nope, not a word either. Could it be that your child has written *SWUM* in joined up writing?

Comment: Could you scan the writing and upload the image? If the word effectively is SMUH then the question should be reopened.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, as i mentioned teacher had marked `smuh`  as correct (✓) word on her notebook. So what if it is not a mistake. I believe verdict on `smuh` is that it should not be taught to small children. I hope others agree in case it was not mistake by either child or teacher.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I can do that tomorrow or later today.

Comment: So the word was really *swum*, eh?

Answer (score 2):

Interesting! As a native English speaker who spends far too much time on the internet, I never even encountered "smuh" before now, so I highly doubt it's mainstream (and thus, not taught in schools).

"Smug" seems more likely to me.

Comment: Smug was also one of the words..

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that your daughter is actually expected to learn the word *smuh*; it's just a piece of Internet slang humor, not (yet!) a regular part of English.

I think it's more likely that the teacher made a mistake; for example, perhaps (s)he meant to write *smush*?

Comment: Agree with you, my major concern is it it was not a mistake on students part then is it right, from feedback & discussion with my English native speaking friends it is should not be their...

Comment: The word *smuh* ~ if it even is a word ~ should **not** be on a child's spelling list ever.

Comment: @CarlSmith: I dunno about "ever". Studies show that phonics-based instruction, where kids are taught how to pay close attention to how the sounds match the letters, is vastly superior to whole-word instruction, which hopes that kids will somehow pick it up on their own. So, while no one should want kids to learn the word *smuh* for its own sake, it might fit in a word list for *sm-*, *-uh*, and so on. (If it were a word.)

Comment: @ruakh - `+1` - That was pretty pedantic, but pretty interesting, so fair play.